# Index out of range in listbox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Consider the following code :

```
Private Sub DelButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DelButton.Click

    If OrderListBox.Text = "" = False Then

        For i As Integer = OrderListBox.SelectedIndex To arr.Count - 1

            arr.RemoveAt(i)

        Next


        OrderListBox.Items.Remove(OrderListBox.SelectedItem)

    End If

    calculate()

End Sub
```

The program crashes at `arr.RemoveAt(i)` and displays the following error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size
>   of the collection.

Comment: what do you mean can you explain more please @HenkHolterman

Answer (score 1):

**First of all, please note that in VB.NET and C#, FOR loops are implemented differently!**

In VB.NET, it works like this:

**BEFORE** the loop starts, you are determining start and end of the loop:

- Start = OrderListBox.SelectedIndex
- End = arr.Count-1

Then, the loop starts.

It is important to know, that in VB.NET, the end of the loop is NOT calculated again anymore. This is an important difference to C#. In C#, the end of the loop is calculated before **each single loop**.

And now, in the loop, you are **DELETING** records from the array.
Therefore, the count of records in the array is **DECREASING**. 
However, your loop is going on, since you have calculated the count of records in the array before the loop started.

Therefore, you are going beyond the range of the array.

You could rewrite your code as follows:

```
   Dim i as Integer
   i = OrderListBox.SelectedIndex
   while i < arr.Count
       arr.RemoveAt(i)
   Next
```

This article covers details about the for loop in VB.NET, especially the section "Technical Implementation": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx

Comment: @HenkHolterman No, you need NOT, because the array is shrinking after each loop iteration!

Answer (score 0):

This error will be thrown when you try to remove an item at an index greater than the size of the collection. i.e when `i` is greater than `arr.Count - 1`.

You should make sure that `OrderListBox.SelectedIndex` is not greater than `arr.Count - 1`. Because if it does, you remove an item that, well, does not exists.

This code is actually displayed in the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As stated, you should do something like this:

```
   Private Sub RemoveTopItems()
   ' Determine if the currently selected item in the ListBox  
   ' is the item displayed at the top in the ListBox. 
   If listBox1.TopIndex <> listBox1.SelectedIndex Then 
   ' Make the currently selected item the top item in the ListBox.
   listBox1.TopIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex
   End If 
   ' Remove all items before the top item in the ListBox. 
   Dim x As Integer 
   For x = listBox1.SelectedIndex - 1 To 0 Step -1
      listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(x)
   Next x

   ' Clear all selections in the ListBox.
   listBox1.ClearSelected()
End Sub 'RemoveTopItems
```

Answer (score -1):

[ListBox.SelectedIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return a value of negative one (-1) is returned if no item is selected.

You didn't check it in your code.

Change your code to this:

```
If OrderListBox.SelectedIndex >= 0 And OrderListBox.Text = "" = False Then
```

**EDIT**

Your code is this:

```
 For i As Integer = OrderListBox.SelectedIndex To arr.Count - 1

        arr.RemoveAt(i)

 Next
```

Let's say your `OrderListBox` contains 3 items : [A, B, C] and the `SelectedIndex` is 0

Then your code will:

- Remove (0) ===> [B, C]
- Remove (1) ===> [B]
- Remove (2) ===> Exception!

You need to reverse the loop

```
 For i As Integer = arr.Count - 1 To OrderListBox.SelectedIndex Step -1

        arr.RemoveAt(i)

 Next
```

Comment: i have tried this and it still gives the same error

Comment: is arr size same with listbox size?

Comment: yeah what ever added to the array list get added to arr

Comment: then try to change `For i As Integer = OrderListBox.SelectedIndex To arr.Count - 1` to `For i As Integer = OrderListBox.SelectedIndex To OrderListBox.Items.Count - 1` and see the result

Comment: This will not fix it. The reason for the error is that he is deleting records from an array, ths decreasing the size of the array, but he is determining the size of the array BEFORE the loop starts. Please note that FOR loops are implemented differently in VB.NET and C#  !